# Unable to connect to SQL instance Database on Google Cloud

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Can anyone help me with a Codeigniter application deployment on Google Cloud App Engine? It seems I need to define `<project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>` somewhere for the mysqli_connect to work (As per this video tutorial goes, I guess that's where it's going wrong - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIWBxx0mE00).. but I don't know where.. or Do I need to mod the mysqli_driver? Anyone?[image: Error when deployed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using App Engine Standard with 2nd Generation MySQL instance. I also tried 1st gen as I saw in some other post here or probably somewhere else, but that did not resolve the issue.

My actual question was how to define the socket in a Codeigniter application if I want to use mysql & connect to the cloud sql instance properly. Well the answer is you need to use PDO as the DB Driver in the config instead of using MySQL/Mysqli.

first one I tried was :

```
'hostname' => NULL,
'socket' =>'/cloudsql/<project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

But this is the one that actually worked :

```
'dsn' => 'mysqli:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>;dbname=<DB_NAME>',
'hostname' => NULL,
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please avoid posting pictures with the stack trace and instead post the full stack trace of the error in the original post. 
Are you using App Engine Flexible or Standard? Also, do you wish to use a Second Generation Cloud SQL instance or a First Generation instance? Are you deploying the application to GAE or trying to run it locally?

If you wish to deploy your application to Google App Engine and you are using a Second Generation Cloud SQL instance, then I would recommend setting up the connection to Cloud SQL following the official documentation that is provided for [GAE Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql) and [GAE Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql) apps.